# Django I Want to pass multiple ids and get their data. Scenario : Social Network system

Tags: mysql, django, orm

This is a code for getting all the followers for a specific id, then passing those ids to then get all their posts/activities from another table. But I can't seem to get that.

```
 @api_view(['GET'])
def build_ecosystem(request, id):
    """
    1. first get all objects that follow the given id
    2. find all the activities posted by all those ids
    3. send the payload 
    """
    list_of_followers,ecosystem_activities = [], []

    def get_object(id):
        try:
            return startup_activities.objects.filter(stup=id)
        except startup_activities.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get_joined_eco_objs(id):
        try:
            return follows.objects.filter(ceo_id__exact=id)
        except startup_activities.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    if request.method == 'GET':
        sd = get_joined_eco_objs(id)
        serializer = FollowerFollowingSerializer(sd, many = True)
        the_list = serializer.data

    for an_item in the_list:
        list_of_followers.append(an_item["stup_follows"])

    for x in range(len(list_of_followers)):
        ecosystem_activities = StupActivitiesSerializer(startup_activities.objects.filter(stup=list_of_followers[x],many = True))

    return Response(ecosystem_activities.data)
```

But when I pass the id I get:
[]

EDIT:
MORE DETAILS:
MODELS :

```
class startup_activities(models.Model):
    stup = models.ForeignKey(startup_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    links = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class follows(models.Model):
    ceo_id = models.ForeignKey(startup_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stup_follows = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class startup_details(models.Model):
    ceo_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    startup_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    startup_about = models.TextField()
    date_founded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def founded_date(self):
        self.date_founded = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

SERIALIZER:

```
class StupActivitiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = startup_activities
        fields = ('stup', 'text', 'links', 'time', 'title')
```

ENDPOINT FOR THE METHOD:

```
    path('get_activities_by_ecofollowers/<int:id>/', views.build_ecosystem, name='build_ecosystem'),
```

Comment: You might need to add a bit more context and dettail.

Comment: Yes. Done......

Comment: There are several ids, a common mistake is passing the wrong id to the wrong methods.

Comment: Also, you're doing a totally unnecessary try..catch. `filter` doesn't raise the `DoesNotExists` error.